# Where can i edit admin thumb size?

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, thumbnail

I already lost many hours without success.
Does anyone know where we can increase admin products thumb grid?
By default it generates a cached picture with 75px but limited to 55px in grid.

[image]

Many thanks.

Comment: which extension are you using for admin catalog grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open
**vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/etc/view.xml** and change width and height

```
<media>
    <images module="Magento_Catalog">
        <image id="product_listing_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>75</height>
        </image>
    </images>
</media>
```

Also you need to change width of following css class:

**.data-grid .data-grid-thumbnail-cell**

**.data-grid .data-grid-thumbnail-cell img**

**NB: Don't modify core file**